# Web api authentication handler by pass for some scenario

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am implemented basic authentication and authorization in web api using AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler.

So before calling any api, the code in this handler gets executed which basically checks whether the user is authenticated or not.

This handler gets executed for each api call. Now my problem is that for few api like login or registration etc. where user is not logged in and I don't need to check the user authentication, how can I bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not get confused between authentication and authorization.

Basically, your `AuthenticationHandler` should **only** authenticate the user and **sets the user identity**.

The point of authentication is to say who this user is (a manager, a teller, an anonymous user,...). You should not reject the request here, it's for authorization. Example code:

```
public class AuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
      protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                           HttpRequestMessage request,
                           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
           //authenticate with your data storage (user,password), or decrypt the information from request's token (I don't know what approach you're doing)
           // here I hardcode just for demo

           //If the user is authenticated (not an anonymous user)
           //create a identity for that user and set the roles for
           //the user. The roles could come from your db or your decrypted token depending on how you implement your code.
           GenericIdentity MyIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("MyUser");
           String[] MyStringArray = {"Manager", "Teller"};
           GenericPrincipal MyPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(MyIdentity, MyStringArray);

           //Set the authenticated principal here so that we can do authorization later.
           Thread.CurrentPrincipal = MyPrincipal;
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               HttpContext.Current.User = MyPrincipal;
           return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
      }
}
```

Authorization happens after authentication to verify whether the user has the rights to access a function. That could be accomplished by applying [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

- On the action method.
- On the controller. **All** the action methods require the user to be **not** anonymous. You can override this in each action method by applying [AllowAnonymousAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)
- Globally by adding the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to the application filters collection. You can use the same technique with [AllowAnonymousAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for specific action methods. Example code extracted from the link:

In your case, you can:

- Add the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) globally to your application filters collection.
- Set an identity in your `AuthHandler` based on the authenticated user.
- Apply [AllowAnonymousAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on your login, registration action methods.

**Side note**: The most prominent authorization approach today is [claims based security](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/leveraging-claims-based-security-in-aspnet-45.aspx). If you have time, you should spend some time to investigate that. Basically, the idea is similar, just that we use claims instead of roles for authorization.

With claims-based in web api, you could subclass [ClaimsAuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement your authorization rules by overriding the `CheckAccess` method.